# Spotify Apps API: Library-class won't return users Playlists

Tags: api, spotify, playlists

I'm trying to get an array containing all Playlists in the users Library (http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/reference/dcdebc652c.html).

No problems with the other class properties (albums, artists, starredPlaylist, tracks), but somehow the "Playlists" property won't work using

```
var allPlaylists = models.library.playlists;
```

whereas

```
var allArtists= models.library.artists;
```

works just fine!(  Both using document.write(var)   )

Any suggestions? thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"?  Is it throwing an error in your console or is it an empty array or null or what?

Comment: sorry,  document.write returns "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like sp.core.library.getPlaylists got disabled in . 
[0.8.0–701-gc2d793a](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines/04_changelog.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the official answer:

Unfortunately, the ability to get the user's playlists in the Spotify Apps API has been removed for privacy reasons. This was done very last-minute, and the documentation wasn't updated in time. We'll be releasing a new build of the client and documentation that reflects this change soon.

Comment: Any update here re: returning users' playlists via api? It's been a while!

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it's a bug with the API.

```
sp = getSpotifyAPI(1);
models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models')
models.library.playlists;

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

try { models.library.playlists } catch(err) { console.log(err.stack) }

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at map (sp:216:20)
    at Library.<anonymous> (eval at evalModule (sp:55:46))
    at unknown source
    at Object._evaluateOn (unknown source)
    at Object._evaluateAndWrap (unknown source)
    at Object.evaluate (unknown source)
```

Digging in the models.js file we see that Library uses sp.core.library.getPlaylists() to get the playlists, which should return an Array but returns undefined:

```
sp.core.library.getPlaylists()

> undefined

sp.core.library.getPlaylists

> function getPlaylists() { [native code] }
```

Since sp.core.library.getPlaylists is native code I am unable to go deeper down the rabbit hole to see what it is doing. So unless the spotify devs say it is the desired behaviour my conclusion is that it is a bug.

Comment: Thanks mate! I looks like sp.core.library.getPlaylists got disabled in . 
[0.8.0–701-gc2d793a](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines/04_changelog.html) 
but without mentioning a reason :S

Comment: Getting a user's playlists is not supported in our API.