# How to create a playlist and get the URI of it in a spotify apps API?

Tags: spotify

It is possible to create a playlist (new Playlist(name)) with the spotify apps API, but the URI field of the new playlist is always null. Anyone know how to get around this, or otherwise reference the new playlist?

Without an URI I can't create a "share" button within the app, since I need the URI in order to reference it.

Anyone know if this is a bug or feature?

I just discovered that spotify removed the ability to read user playlists for privacy reasons[1], so now I'm wondering if this is a design decision or simply a bug. After all, the playlist in question was created in our app, so I should be able to get the URI of it?

1: [Spotify Apps API: Library-class won't return users Playlists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627627/spotify-apps-api-library-class-wont-return-users-playlists)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the URI property will only be filled if you instantiate the playlist with a URI given to you, like:

```
models.Playlist.FromURI("totally a valid URI");
```

Unfortunately, this is because playlist URIs contain the username of the creator, and we're not allowed to release personally-identifying information through our API.

We hope to change this in the future.

Comment: This is a really interesting point. I assume that's also why library.getPlaylists() was depreciated. Perhaps you need some sort of anonymous playlist url....

Comment: Yes, that's the best long-term solution in my opinion. In the short-term, we're considering making a better share widget that you can give a playlist/etc to.

Comment: is there any news on this? it's bad if you can't open the same playlist you generated in the next session of the app.