# How to get the URI of a playlist creating it inside the spotify app with the spotify apps API?

Tags: api, uri, spotify

I have read this question: [How to create a playlist and get the URI of it in a spotify apps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802989/how-to-create-a-playlist-and-get-the-uri-of-it-in-a-spotify-apps-api?rq=1)

But I was wondering if now it's possible to do it, or if you can give me a solution, I really need the URI, could I create a public Playlist or sth similar? I need that to create a App similar to soundrop :)

Thank you a lot

Sara

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a playlist and get the URI of it in a spotify apps API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802989/how-to-create-a-playlist-and-get-the-uri-of-it-in-a-spotify-apps-api)

Comment: SoundDrop can only get playlist URIs by having the user drag the playlists onto the app.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible today. The CoffeeScript example below works to me

```
sp = getSpotifyApi 1
models = sp.require 'sp://import/scripts/api/models'

exports.exports.init = ->
  playlist = new models.Playlist()
  console.log "The temporary playlist is " + playlist.uri
```