# User field missing from Spotify playlists.tracks object in Apps API

Tags: spotify, playlist

I've been hacking with the Spotify Apps API, specifically the playlists methods, however it seems that the user field deos not exist in the playlist.tracks object.

An example from the inspector:

Playlist loaded [
Track
data: Object
album: Object
artists: Array[1]
availability: 0
availableForPlayback: true
discNumber: 0
duration: 280000
isAd: false
isInvalid: false
isLoaded: true
isLocal: false
isPlaceholder: false
name: "Nothing Left To Say"
popularity: 29
starred: false
trackNumber: 13
type: "track"
uri: "spotify:track:24wKpBad6OrQKseDQnw1Fr"

I am interested in this information for two reasons:
1. To scrub playback statistics from shared playlists, for later analysis/usage in building apps, playlists etc
2. If I were to need to rebuild my playlists, when I add the songs they will all have me as the user, not the original person

seems strange this field is missing, but as yet I have not found it, currently I export the playlist to a database, sort the tracks by username, and then as the number of users is small its rather quick to fill in the appropriate username based on the track/user boundaries, though this doesn't help when rebuilding playlists.

The info must be there as the Spotify desktop client shows this, but I guess it's a private API?

Cheers
SockThief

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, this information isn't available through the Apps API for privacy reasons. Sorry!

Comment: I suspected as much, yet don't full understand the reasoning! If I have a shared playlist, I know the URI and I can view it in the desktop application along with the user information, but not from the API. If the user information was viewable via the API, at best I could scrub a list of users - shouldn't the privacy lockdown be on extracting user information, rather than the user name?

Comment: Since usernames are often used across multiple services, the username counts as personally identifying information so it's withheld.

Comment: Shouldn't this then be extended to the desktop application? I'm actually after nothing other than the desktop application gives me, I'm just too lazy to manually perform the operation everytime the playlists changes...

Comment: based on a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802989/how-to-create-a-playlist-and-get-the-uri-of-it-in-a-spotify-apps-api you are required to already have the playlist URI, which, unless I have a list of playlist URIs, I must already have the usernames in the desktop application anyway and, if the playlist is mine already, then I must have shared that with others to have them contribute to the playlist, which, again means that I already know the username. A compromise, would be that if the playlist is owned by the person running the app, the user information can be shown

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really the place to discuss our privacy policy, sorry.

Comment: Fully agree, I've accepted your answer to close this question off - what is the most appropriate forum to bring this up in?