# Spotify iPhone API to search playlists

Tags: iphone, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0, playlists

I am implementing Spotify service in iPhone. I want to search playlists in Spotify. Is there any API in Spotify to get it.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to check out the [documentation](https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify/tree/master/Documentation) for the `SPSearch` class, there are methods there which allow you to search for playlists (among other things).

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the below link says it is not possible.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627627/spotify-apps-api-library-class-wont-return-users-playlists

Comment: Sorry -- your question wasn't very clear. I thought you were just looking for the ability to search for playlists. Getting a list of a user's playlist is a different matter entirely, and as you correctly noted, is not possible for privacy reasons.

Comment: Is there any difference between libSpotify and libCocoaLibSpotify.

Comment: libspotify is a native C library, cocoaLibSpotify is an obj-c wrapper around libspotify which makes it easier to work with in iOS and Mac OSX.