# Access a user's playlists?

Tags: javascript, spotify

I've been reading through some of the spotify app javascript API docs. I'm unclear if I am able to access a user's playlists or not. `Toplist` isn't what I am looking for. I'd like to be able to iterate a user's playlists and allow them to perform actions against them without having to drag/drop them. Based on the [`User`](http://www.hackerden.org/spotify/preview/docs/User.html) docs I don't think this is something that you can freely access, with or without having the user allow you to connect to them via Facebook/Twitter. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to retrieve user's playlists at the moment (see [Spotify Apps API: Library-class won't return users Playlists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627627/spotify-apps-api-library-class-wont-return-users-playlists)). You do have access to artists and tracks that a user is subscribed to, by using the [`Library`](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/dcdebc652c.html) object.

If you still need to process user's playlists then you will need to use drag and drop.