# Spotify API - Obtaining Information About User's Albums

Tags: javascript, spotify

According to the Spotify API, I can use the [Library](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/dcdebc652c.html) object to obtain an array of all of the albums that a user has in their library. However, when I enter the following preliminary code:

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var models = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/api/models");
var userlib = models.library;
```

followed by a call to the albums attribute:

```
document.write(userlib.albums);
```

I get nothing, presumably because the albums attribute is undefined. If I try it on the other attributes listed in Spotify's documentation, including `.artists` and `.tracks`, it does exactly what it should: lists every artist/track included in the user's library. Any Spotify experts have an idea as to why this album functionality isn't present and where it might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an obscure, undocumented way to grab an array of all of the albums in a user's library that I found after a lot of aimless searching. After the initial call to Spotify's API, usually done like this:

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
```

you can then make this call:

```
var albums = sp.core.library.getAlbums();
```

returning an array of Album objects in the user's library. You can access the methods and attributes spelled out in the Documentation's Album object.

I don't know if this is some kind of hold over from an older version of Spotify's API, but I hope it sticks around or they replace it with something better. Albums as a piece of data are still very important to many listeners, as much as Spotify seems to want to erode them with Playlists.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, albums are not available through the API. Documentation should be definitely updated. Have a look at [Spotify Apps API: Library-class won't return users Playlists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627627/spotify-apps-api-library-class-wont-return-users-playlists) question.